# How do you group by multiple columns in LINQ TO SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, group-by

How do you group by multiple columns in LINQ TO SQL?

```
db.Table.GroupBy(a => a.column1.ToString() + a.column2.ToString())
```

It seems ugly and with poor performance, and I don't even know if it works. Which is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try grouping by an anonymous type:

```
group by new { item.Col1, item.Col2 }
```

you'll then be able to access Key.Col1, etc

Comment: Does it works? AnonTypes implement Equals and GetHashCode automatically so you don't have to worry about it?

Comment: Just tested it, and you're right. Test code:             var a = new { A = 1, B = 2 };
            var b = new { A = 1, B = 2 };
            var c = new { A = 1, B = 3 };
            Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(a, c);

Comment: yeah it works, it's the official way. here's a good reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx